# Wiremock: how to match a JSON request that does NOT have a specific property?

Tags: json, rest, testing, wiremock

I'm trying to mock an API call that accepts a JSON body in a POST and it has two possible responses:

1. if body contains `SearchCenter` property, answer with response A
2. if body does NOT contain `SearchCenter`, answer with response B

In the [Request Matching](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/) chapter of Wiremock documentation it only shows how to *positively* match JSON, it does not show how to match missing properties.

Sample request with `SearchCenter`:

```
{
    "GeoCoordinatesResponseFormat": "DecimalDegree",
    "ProviderID": "bla bla",
    "SearchCenter": {
        "GeoCoordinates": {
            "DecimalDegree": {
                "Latitude": "{{search_lat}}",
                "Longitude": "{{search_lon}}"
            }
        },
        "Radius": {{search_radius}}
    }
}
```

Sample request without `SearchCenter`:

```
{
    "GeoCoordinatesResponseFormat": "DecimalDegree",
    "ProviderID": "bla bla"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I may have gotten ahead of myself -- I think there is an easier solution for matching. You could use [negative matching with regex](https://medium.com/@jw_ng/my-complete-reference-for-wiremock-request-matching-5b933d6c3852). (Negative Lookahead) I still think I prefer the priorities method.

```
stubFor(any(urlPathEqualTo("/some-endpoint"))
    .withRequestBody(matchingJsonPath("$.?!SearchCenter"))
    .willReturn(ok("Body does not contain Search Center"));

stubFor(any(urlPathEqualTo("/some-endpoint"))
    .withRequestBody(matchingJsonPath("$.SearchCenter"))
    .willReturn(ok("Body does contain Search Center"));
```

There are two ways you can accomplish this. The first would use a regex matcher/not matcher. Assuming you're using stubs...

```
stubFor(any(urlPathEqualTo("/some-endpoint"))
    .withRequestBody(notMatching("\"SearchCenter\": \{ .* \}"))
    .willReturn(ok("Body does not contain Search Center"));

stubFor(any(urlPathEqualTo("/some-endpoint"))
    .withRequestBody(matchingJsonPath("$.SearchCenter"))
    .willReturn(ok("Body does contain Search Center"));
```

This does a regex match on not matching for checking if the field does not exist, and then JSON path matching for the case where the field does exist. (I didn't test out the actual code, so the regex matching / JSON path might need some tweaking.)

However, I think a better solution would be to have a more specific match return one response, and the less specific match return the other response. We can achieve this through priorities.

```
stubFor(any(urlPathEqualTo("/some-endpoint"))
    .atPriority(1)
    .withRequestBody(matchingJsonPath("$.SearchCenter"))
    .willReturn(ok("Body does contain Search Center"));

stubFor(any(urlPathEqualTo("/some-endpoint"))
    .atPriority(2)
    .willReturn(ok("Body does not contain Search Center"));
```

[Information on Priorities can be found here](http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/). The tl;dr on Priorities is that they force WireMock to check for certain matches before others. In this case, we're going to check if the request body contains the field we want ("Search Center") and if it does, we return a match. If we had other stubs at the same priority (1), those would also get checked before moving onto the next priority. In the case where the field we want to match on is not found, we move to the next priority. Because the stub at Priority 2 does not need to match the JSON Path in the Request Body, we will match.

My preference for priorities over specific matching twice is simply because I like the "fallback" behavior that having a generic stub provides, where any calls to "/some-endpoint" will be fulfilled with the generic response.

Comment: I like the Priority solution better for two reasons: 1) regexes are hard to read and maintain and 2) using priorities better reflects how routes are handled by backend

Comment: This does not work for me in latest version. Only `matchingJsonPath("$.xxx", absent())` works.

Comment: I went over two answers in this  -- which answer does not work?

Comment: `matchingJsonPath("$.?!SearchCenter")` I mean this.

Answer (score 5):

In order to match a missing JSON property, you can use the `matchingJsonPath` operator in combination with the `absent()`, like this:

```
.withRequestBody(matchingJsonPath("$.SearchCenter", absent()))
```

Comment: Note that this also matches null properties, which may not be desired behavior.

Comment: When using mapping files, you need to use this:

`{
        "matchesJsonPath": {
          "expression": "$.SearchCenter",
          "absent": "(absent)"
        }
      }`

Because i ended here without finding the answer for my mapping file problem, i comment it here

Comment: The other one(use regex negate in regex) does not work for me, but this one does. Thanks.