# Using regex to negate a filter in wiremock jsonpath

Tags: jsonpath, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am using wiremock for stubbing and it uses Jayway JsonPath.

I want to create a stub only when the json element **doesn't** contain exactly 10 digits.

stub is

```
"request": {
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "matchingJsonPath": "$.employees[?(@.employeeContact =~/[^0-9]{10}/)]"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have tried multiple combinations like:

```
1. $.employees[?(@.employeeContact =~/[^0-9]{10}/)]
2. $.employees[?(@.employeeContact =~/^[0-9]{10}/)]
3. $.employees[?(@.employeeContact !=~/[0-9]{10}/)]
4. $.employees[?(@.employeeContact <>~/[^0-9]{10}/)]
```

But none of these have worked.
Example json which should NOT work:

```
{
"employee": {
    "employeeContact": "1234567890"
}
}
```

while these employee should work (anything other than 10 digits):

```
 1. "employeeContact": "1a34567890"  // character in between
 2. "employeeContact": "12345678901" // more than 10
 3. "employeeContact": "123456789"   // less than 10
 4. "employeeContact": "123456 89"   //space
```

Comment: There's a spelling error in your matcher - `mathcingJsonPath` instead of `matching`

Comment: thanks for pointing out, corrected it.

Comment: What about https://stackoverflow.com/a/62794546/2193968

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
"bodyPatterns": [{
    "matchesJsonPath": "$.employees[?(@.employeeContact =~/[^0-9]{1,9}/ || $.employees[?(@.employeeContact =~/[^0-9]{11,}/)]" 
    }]
```

Watch that it is `matchesJsonPath` instead of `matchingJsonPath`.
Even with that `"or"` didnt work with my wiremock 2.28.1 so may well be a wiremock bug.

Comment: Logical `and` and `or` were not released until WireMock 2.29.0.

Answer (score 1):

[You could use the `logical or` operator](https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#logical-and-and-or) to match for lengths less than 10 and greater than 10.

```js
"bodyPatterns": [
  "or": [
    { "matchingJsonPath": "$.employees[?(@.employeeContact =~/[^0-9]{1,9}/)]" },
    { "matchingJsonPath": "$.employees[?(@.employeeContact =~/[^0-9]{11,}/)]" }
  ]
]
```

Comment: I can but using this given me: "error parsing JSON" with the details "Cannot deserualise value of type 'java.util.ArrayList<com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.ContentPattern<Java.lang.Object>>' from Object value (token 'JsonToken.START_OBJECT')"

Comment: I think this should work.  Surely that error would be a bug in WireMock?

Comment: "bodyPatterns": [{
    "matchesJsonPath": "$.employees[?(@.employeeContact =~/[^0-9]{1,9}/ || $.employees[?(@.employeeContact =~/[^0-9]{11,}/)]" 
 }]

Comment: Logical `and` and `or` were not released until WireMock 2.29.0, so no bug, OP is just using a lower version than where this was implemented.